# Framework not found Crashlytics in xcode 12.0.1

Tags: swift, xcode, firebase, cocoapods, crashlytics

After i implement firebase Crashlytics on old project it has fabric.
i removed those pods :

> pod 'Fabric'
>
> pod 'Crashlytics'

**and after**

> pod install

**i see this error**

ld: framework not found Fabric
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have tried many clean build folder and project. But It still stays in there. What should I do?

> **Solution**

- Goto your project target and Build Settings
- search for "Other Linker Flags"
- Delete :
  -framework
  "Crashlytics"

[Crashlytics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fOH5.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upgrade, just follow the upgrade guide here:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/upgrade-sdk?platform=ios

If you want to just remove Crashlytics, use `pod deintegrate`

Comment: i walk through the upgrade guide but still the error exist till i use the solution i provided in the edit it worked.